# Exhausted my knee?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I have an old problem with my left knee. And if I am not careful, I end up having internal bleeding in it.

I was  travelling in and out of my work place the whole week and now my knee feels funny.

Which word should I use to tell my friend that like I *exhausted my knee*

Any other word?

Comment: Could be: I overdid it with my knee.  Or: I overdid things with my knee.  Or: I overused my knee.  Or: I wasn't careful with me knee and now I'm having a lot of pain.

Comment: 'Exhausted' isn't right?

Comment: I’ve pushed my knee past its limits.  I’ve overtaxed my knee.  I was too hard on my knee.  I really abused my knee.

Comment: *Exhaust* usually has some connection with having used *something* up. You sound like you're trying to describe an injury, or a weakness or the frailty that comes from one - that's not exhaustion.

Comment: I have damaged my knee... my reoccurring knee problem has come back... I have placed too much strain on my knee and now my old problem has come back... all work fine

Comment: I would say "overworked".  Or "aggravated".

Comment: Other options: I injured my knee, I re-injured my knee, I aggravated an old knee injury, I threw my knee out, I screwed up my knee, I messed up my knee, I twisted my knee, I sprained my knee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments clarify, the verb *exhaust* is used improperly in this instance, it is not idiomatic to say *I have exhausted my knee*. The  OP has probably confused this with **exacerbated**. You *“exacerbate an old injury.”*

I'm not a doctor but it sounds like you have *Hemarthrosis* the medical term for **joint bleeding**. This condition can be [exacerbated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exacerbate) by a severe sprain.

A sprain is an injury that usually occurs when a joint has been twisted which causes pain and swelling but not dislocation.

Wikipedia has this to say

> **[Sprains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprain)** typically occur when the joint is taken beyond its functional range of motion.
>
> There are certain factors which increase the risk of sprains. Fatigue of muscles generally leads to sprains. When one suddenly starts to exercise after a sedentary lifestyle, sprains are quite common.

The OP's description “And if I am not careful, I end up having internal bleeding in it.… now my knee feels funny” seems to confirm the following symptoms of joint bleeding

> Early signs that you are having a joint bleed:
>
> - You get a hard hit to the joint.
> - You have an "aura".  An aura is a special, hard-to-explain feeling that some people with hemophilia get when they start to have a bleed.
> - There is a bubbling or tingling feeling in the joint.
> - The joint feels warm inside.
>     [Source](https://www.hog.org/handbook/article/3/33/joint-bleeds)

After visiting a medic, the OP could describe the recurring injury as a *bleeding knee joint*, or simply say

> I've **severely damaged** my knee joint
>   I've **strained** my knee joint **badly**

Comment: @pluto20010 glad to have helped, and thank you for the green checkmark.

Comment: You deserve it. Your reputation is a proof of it as well. Not being creepy but I wish I had people like you around me in real life as well. So empathetic! :')